# is it possible to automaticaly release the mouse to get off a guest in Linux VMware workstation 7.1?

Tags: vmware-workstation

VMware workstation is the version 7.1.1 on a Archlinux host.
Guest is a windows XP 32bit with VMware tools installed.

I wonder if it's even possible to easylly switch between guest and host without the need to type ctrl+alt combo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VMWare Tools installed in the guest then you should be able to simply click in a guest window or host window without typing ctrl+alt.  I have used a similar configuration (Fedora host, Win 7 guest) which worked.

Are you able to select Unity mode?  While you may not want to run in Unity mode, if you're unable to select it, it may mean that VMWare Tools aren't installed properly.  Try reinstalling VMWare Tools, and make sure you installed the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for your advice goroco. I'm able to use unity mode, so VMware tools is correctly installed if I understand well. So, maybe my version of Windows is not fully supported !? I don't have more explanations about my need to type ctrl+alt every times (boring me)...